# Why does populating an ADO.NET DataTable from within a lambda expression result in an empty DataTable?

Tags: c#, lambda, datatable, ado.net

I'm trying to populate a [.NET 4.5 DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.DataTable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from a `List<T>`, where `T` is a class with a property of type `string`.

I have a function `makeNewDataTable()` which creates a `DataTable` instance and adds a set of columns to it; this part is working fine.

When I manually iterate over the list, the correct number of rows (with correct data) are added to the DataTable:

```cs
DataTable dataTable = makeNewDataTable();
if (inputList != null)
{
    //inputList.Select(item => dataTable.Rows.Add(item.Property, DBNull.Value));
    foreach (var item in inputList)
    {
        dataTable.Rows.Add(item.Property, DBNull.Value);
    }
}
```

However, if I try to use a lambda expression to the same end:

```cs
DataTable dataTable = makeNewDataTable();
if (inputList != null)
{
    inputList.Select(item => dataTable.Rows.Add(item.Property, DBNull.Value));
    //foreach (var item in inputList)
    //{
    //    dataTable.Rows.Add(item.Property, DBNull.Value);
    //}
}
```

then after the `if` statement's closing `}` I see that `dataTable.Rows.Count == 0`.

**Why don't I see the rows as having been added when I use the lambda expression, when the manually coded foreach loop works fine?**

*Bonus question:* Is there a way to do what I want using the more concise syntax of lambda expressions rather than manually coding a foreach loop?

Comment: The second one is returning a data table object list but is not being assigned to anything. if you were to do "var table = inputList.Select...." then do a row count on that what happens?

Comment: @StevenWood I'm not sure at all that applies, since the `.Select()` expression maps from each item to a function call to add the row to `dataTable` which is defined outside of the lambda expression. Or at least that was what I thought it'd do, but the code clearly doesn't do quite what I intended. The full `.Select()` statement doesn't return anything meaningful here.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select is an iterator. Lambda defines how IEnumerable will be populated after enumaration starts. But it starts after you use foreach over the result of select or force enumeration with ToList() or ToArray() or GetEnumerator().MoveNext()... It is deferred execution.
2. It's not recommended to perform such operations as Add in Select. Since it can be executed in parallel by default in future versions of .NET and Add can be not thread-safe

There is nothing bad in "oldschool" foreach, you should use lambdas when you have reasons to: working with expression trees, capturing contexts, fast anonymous method creation in scenarios when you forced to pass delegate/expression.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the question why, but I can answer the bonus question: for this purpose, you should use the [List.ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
inputList.ForEach(item => dataTable.Rows.Add(item.Property, DBNull.Value));
```

Note however that it is only available on a value of type `List`, and not `IList` or `IEnumerable`, so you may have to call `ToList()`.

Comment: this has no advantages over foreach(){} (only possibility to pass delegate) + has overhead for parsing lambda + extra call + worse readability (long chains etc).Main reasons why there is no standart ForEach extension method available  for IEnumerable<T> is confusing laziness and side-effects.